# Async servlet responses in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create something like chat in my app, but I have a problem with capturing changes in real time.
My javascript code seems to work fine

```
function load() {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log("Response nr" + id++ + ". " + xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "/new", true);
xhr.send();
}

function sendMessage() {
...
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

var params = ...
request.open("POST", "/new", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send(params); 
}
```

But spring sends response only once (only after first post request)

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

private final MessageRepository messageRepository;
private final Queue<DeferredResult<List<Message>>> messagesQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

@Autowired
public MessageController(MessageRepository messageRepository) {
    this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
}


@RequestMapping("/new")
public DeferredResult<List<Message>> get() {
    final DeferredResult<List<Message>> deferredResult
            = new DeferredResult<>();
    this.messagesQueue.add(deferredResult);

    return deferredResult;
}

@RequestMapping( value = "/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void postMessage(...) {
    Message message = ...
    ...
    this.messageRepository.save(message);


    for (DeferredResult<List<Message>> result: this.messagesQueue) {
        List<Message> messages = this.messageRepository.findAll();
        result.setResult(messages);
      //this.messagesQueue.remove(result);
    }
}
```

(Yes, I know that sending all messages every time isn't a good idea, I'll fix it later) 
I saw some examples on spring.io/blog, but they don't work in my case. Uncommenting the last line doesn't solve the problem. What should I do? 
 
PS. I have EnableAsync annotation and I'm using spring boot configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the get() method you add an empty DeferredResult to the messagesQueue and return it to the client. I cannot see, what happens with the queue, but its very likely that its still empty.

In postMessage() you prepare a result, but you do not return it.

It looks a little strange, to write on GET and to read on PUT.
So I think you might have to rethink what you are actually want to achieve....

Comment: It wasn't my concept at all, I found it [here](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/16/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-chat-sample/)